# Android: Ensure view under EditText not hidden by Keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, textview

The simple issue: I have a live "Text Remaining" view directly underneath the edit text that is hidden whether I use adjustPan or adjustResize. I want to ensure the TextView is displayed (otherwise, it's pretty pointless.) Any thoughts?

Comment: One solution is provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505374/keyboard-placement-obscures-view-below-edittext-would-like-to-keep-visible