# Keyboard placement obscures view below EditText would like to keep visible

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an activity that is basically a long form of entry fields.
On each row, I want to show a TextView to serve as hint text just below each EditText and I want the TextView to remain visible at all times when the user is entering data.  Unfortunately, the soft keyboard obscures the hint text and always positions itself immediately below the EditText.  Is there any technique that will allow the TextView below the EditText to also be visible when the soft keyboard appears and the contents are adjusted (via windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize|adjustPan), without having the user scroll ?

Answer (score 3):

Vishavjeet got me on the right track in suggesting I scrolldown to reveal the view that may be overlapped by the keyboard.  Below is a function similar to what I used to solve the problem.  It can be called when the EditText above the TextView receives focus:

```
    //       View targetView; // View that may be hidden by keyboard
    //       ScrollView scrollContainerView; // Scrollview containing hiddenView
    //
    void assureViewVisible (View targetView, ScrollView, scrollContainerView) {        
        Window rootWindow = activity.getWindow();
        Rect rMyView = new Rect();
        View rootview = rootWindow.getDecorView();
        rootview.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rMyView); // Area not taken up by keyboard

        int subTextPos[] = new int[2];
        targetView.getLocationInWindow(subTextPos); // Get position of targetView
        int subTextHt = targetView.getHeight();     // Get bottom of target view

        if ((subTextPos[1]+subTextHt) > rMyView.bottom) { // Is targetView at all obscured?
           int scrollBy = (subTextPos[1]+subTextHt) - rMyView.bottom + 10; // add a small bottom margin
           mMeasurementViewScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, scrollBy); // Scroll to subtext
        }
   }
```

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
By understanding the problem more deeply, I think that you should add scroll programatically when user clicks on the Edittext. Here is the code to do that:

```
private final void focusOnView()
{ 
 new Handler().post(new Runnable() 
 { 
 @Override
 public void run() 
 { 
 your_scrollview.scrollTo(0, your_EditBox.getBottom()); 
 }}); 
 }
```

From my personal experience I think there is not such way to do that. The thing you can do is place the hint textview toRightOf the editext. Or Use modern Approach by using a Hint Placeholder on Edittext:

In XML, it's simply `android:hint="someText"`

Programatically you can use `edittext.setHint(int);`

pass R.string.somestring in above method.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the alternatives.  I'm looking for a solution to my specific design.

Comment: You can scroll your view programtically if the fileds are enclosed in a scrollview. You can call this function on onClick() method of edittext
`private final void focusOnView(){
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                your_scrollview.scrollTo(0, your_EditBox.getBottom());
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: Now that could work!  I will give it a try.  I will probably want to scroll in the onFocusChange listener.

Comment: Vishavjeet, I was able to come up with a reasonable solution based on your comment.  Please provide another answer or modify your first answer so I can accept it and give you credit!

Comment: It is only necessary to scroll if view in question is overlapped by keyboard: